# Chrome vs. FF button click behavior

Tags: html, css, button, cross-browser, click

I used the :active pseudoclass on my buttons to change the padding and border color when clicked. This visually mimics a button press. [See an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/4/)

Works in FF. In Chrome, though, the clicks don't always register. Specifically, if you click-and-hold on the text inside the button, then drag off the text (but still inside the button), the click will not fire. Same goes if you click in the padding, then drag into the text.

I've read weird things about buttons and padding in FF vs. Chrome but I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: It works for me wherever I click/drag? (Chrome v20.0.1132.3 dev-m)

Comment: Hmm, I am using 19.0.1084.36 beta-m ... Although I've noticed this on many different installs and machines, one of which I just fresh installed Chrome on last week.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this on Chrome 19. Firefox 12 behaves as expected as you noted.

Comment: You should also consider reporting this on the Chromium issue tracker, as it does not seem a very rational behavior on Chrome's part.

Comment: Okay, thanks lanzz and gmeben. I first needed just a sanity check that I wasn't making some silly mistake. The first wave of responses made me think I was going crazy.

Comment: Works in Firefox Aurora 14.0a2 (2012-05-30).

Comment: This is a bug in WebKit, which was apparently recently fixed in Blink (for Chrome), though I'm not seeing it yet: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39620

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution: Give it a Single Thing to Click

Adding a `position: relative` to the `button` and then overlaying it with a `:before` pseudo element like so:

```
button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Seemed to resolve the bug for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/23/). I imagine it resolves the bug (which I do think it is a bug) by giving a single "element" to focus upon when it is clicked.

Comment: Fantastic, a css-only solution. To, me all the other answers screamed "WORKAROUND," adding event listeners to every button and yada yada. But yours is way cleaner. You're getting the bounty if nobody else comes up with a better one =D.

Comment: This fix appears to function on button elements but NOT input elements with type="button" :/

Comment: @JSP64: [That's because pseudo-elements do not work on `input` elements because they are "replaced elements."](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info)

Comment: @ScottS: +1, thanks for the explanation, I've learned something.  Interestingly, that wiki says `<button>` elements are also "replaced elements" - although I'm not sure why since the content of the `<button>` element would be between `<button>` tags whereas the content of the `<input />` element would exist as a value.  Meanwhile, I'm still trying to figure out a way around this bug that doesn't entail replacing all my `<input type="button"/>` and `<input type="submit"/>` with button tags or rewriting all my code to look at the onmouseup event :)

Comment: @JSP64: I'm going to have to investigate that further. I do think the reason it works on `button` is because it contains content, but if it is in fact a replaced element, then that alone is apparently not the whole reason the pseudo-element does not work and the wiki should be revised. If you are experiencing this problem with `input` then I would bet any solution will be messing with adding/changing the html.

Comment: @JSP64: I think the wiki is incorrectly based off [this definition](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements). The [CSS 2.1 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element) does't list specific elements, stating that "content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model." The [drafts of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#replaced-elements) do not list `<button>` as a replaced element, but also do not list `<select>`. Replaced elements do not support pseudo-elements, and some other bound or non-content elements do not as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/9/

Instead of checking for both `mousedown` and `mouseup` on the same element, check only for `mousedown` on your button and then check for `mouseup` on any other element.

Comment: Any other element? In the entire document? It's normal behavior for buttons to disregard mousedowns if the mouseup happened outside the button, in order to let the user "cancel" their decision mid-click. This is changing paradigms...

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to re-read the question a few more times. I'm not dragging OFF the button. I'm dragging from the TEXT into the PADDING.

Comment: Then just change `html` to `this` in the JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/10/

Answer (score 1):

Your button works great in Chrome. I have fixed the "click-and-hold on the text inside the button" thing by few lines of CSS and a attribute for IE.
http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/2/

EDIT:
This is a screenshot of the bug I fixed:

[image]

Comment: Didn't it fix the text selection issue?

Comment: Your button works 100% in my Chrome, didn't skip a single click.

Comment: I never said anything about text selection. All I know is that if you drag on/off the text, the button doesn't register a click. I don't see any text getting selected.

Comment: This is what you wrote in OP: "Specifically, if you click-and-hold on the text inside the button"

Comment: But now I see that you meant something else. You are actually not aware of the issue I have fixed so never mind.

Comment: Yea, but the thought of "text selection" never entered my head. I was dragging vertically (click down on button, drag straight down to close to the edge, then let go of click).

Comment: Edited my post with a screenshot

Comment: Oh... how did that happen? I've never seen the button text get selected like that... Anyway, my question was a different problem.

Comment: Hold the mouse cursor near the button on the right and start dragging onto the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/22/</del> http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/25/

This is how it works:

1. Initialize 'down' to false
2. mousedown on button causes 'down' to be true
3. On mouseup/click, if 'down' is true, append text 'click' and set 'down' to false

Clicking triggers a click.

Dragging the text into the padding triggers a click.

Dragging the padding into the text triggers a click.

Dragging from the inside to the outside does **not** trigger a click.

Dragging from outside to inside does **not** trigger a click.

Here is the code:

```
var down=false;
$("button").mousedown(function() {
    down=true;
});
$("button").mouseup(function() {
    if(down) {
        $("#clicks").append("<div>click</div>");
    }
    down=false;
});
$("button").click(function() {
    if(down) {
        $("#clicks").append("<div>click</div>");
    }
    down=false;
});
```

Comment: I still get no click event on Chrome 21. It might be a bug.

Comment: @SomethVictory - which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: I am using 18.0.1025.162. But this should support most of browser version, and also various browser as well.

Comment: @SomethVictory - does [this updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuJ/25/) work? I added a `mouseup` function identical to the `click` function. Also, I downloaded Chrome 20 beta (20.0.1132.21), and my version(s) work with that too...

Answer (score 0):

After having playing around with your example, I think I got what happen behind the scene. By default click event will check both mousedown and mouseup event to be fired before it fires the callback. The problem is that you click on the text, your current target is the text now(it means mousedown event is already fired inside the text area, and it's waiting for mouseup event to be fired in order to complete a click event). However, you drag cursor out of the text and release mouse outside the text area, and your current target now is the Button, not the text anymore(mouseup event doesn't fire inside text area, but inside button area), so click event won't happen. However, if you click on the text and drag, and release your mouse inside text area, it will works just fine. This is the problem of event bubbling or capturing. In jQuery we have event.stopPropagation() or event.stopImmediatePropagation, but it just works for FF, not in Chrome.

What I suggest is using mousedown and mouseup event instead of click event.

Answer (score 0):

Use "mouseup" instead of "click", it should work in ie, chrome and ff.

```
 var elementName = "";

    $("button").mouseup(function() {

        if (elementName != "" && elementName == "BUTTON") {


            $("#clicks").append("<span>click</span><br/>");
            elementName = "";
        }

    });


    $("button").mousedown(function() {

        elementName = $(this).get(0).tagName;

    });
```

Comment: This event fires even if the click is initiated outside of the button, which I'm guessing is not the desired functionality.

Comment: I have edited the code, try it, its a workaround to cater the issue.